# Why does type int exist in Go

Tags: go

There's `int, int32, int64` in `Golang`.

```
int32 has 32 bits,
int64 has 64 bits,
int has 32 or 64 or different number of bits according to the environment.
```

I think `int32` and `int64` will be totally enough for the program.
I don't know why `int` type should exist, doesn't it will make the action of our code harder to predict?

And also in `C++`, type `int` and type `long` have uncertain length. I think it will make our program fragile. I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 6):

Usually size of `int` is equal to the natural word size of target. So if your program doesn't care for the size of `int` (Minimal `int` range is enough), it can perform best on variety of compilers.

When you need a specific size, you can of course use `int32` etc.

Answer (score 6):

Usually each platform operates best with integral type of its native size.

By using simple `int` you say to your compiler that you don't really care about what bit width to use and you let him choose the one it will work fastest with. Note, that you always want to write your code so that it is as platform independent as possible...

On the other hand `int32` / `int64` types are useful if you need the integer to be of a specific size. This might be useful f.e. if you want to save binary files (don't forget about endiannes). Or if you have large array of integers (that will only reach up to 32b value), where saving half the memory would be significant, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In versions of Go up to 1.0, `int` was just a synonym for `int32` — a 32-bit Integer.  Since `int` is used for indexing slices, this prevented slices from having more than 2 billion elements or so.

In Go 1.1, [`int` was made 64 bits long on 64-bit platforms](https://golang.org/doc/go1.1#int), and therefore large enough to index any slice that fits in main memory.  Therefore:

- `int32` is the type of 32-bit integers;
- `int64` is the type of 64-bit integers;
- `int` is the smallest integer type that can index all possible slices.

In practice, `int` is large enough for most practical uses.  Using `int64` is only necessary when manipulating values that are larger than the largest possible slice index, while `int32` is useful in order to save memory and reduce memory traffic when the larger range is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause for this is array addressability. If you came into a situation where you needed to call `make([]byte, 5e9)` your 32 bit executable would be unable to comply, while your 64 bit executable could continue to run. Addressing an array with `int64` on a 32 bit build is wasteful. Addressing an array with `int32` on a 64 bit build is insufficient. Using `int` you can address an array to its maximum allocation size on both architectures without having to code a distinction using `int32`/`int64`.